# Unix Sockets: Client stops receiving messages correctly after first message

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

**Info**

```
[root@xilinx Downloads]# uname -a
Linux xilinx 2.6.32-71.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 1 01:33:01 EDT 2010 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am trying to make a simple chat application using Unix sockets:

After compiling the code I first run **server** on one terminal and it says, waiting for connection. And then I start **client** on another terminal on the same computer, it connects successfully. The client then send the first message. Server receives it perfectly well.

But after that something weird happens.  I have to enter several times to get it working and get the entire message.

Here is a simple run output :

**Server side**

```
[root@xilinx Downloads]# ./server 
Waiting for a connection...
Connected.
```

**Client Side**

```
[root@xilinx Downloads]# 
[root@xilinx Downloads]# 
[root@xilinx Downloads]# ./client 
Trying to connect...
Connected.
```

> SingleWord   //cleint sends this message to server

**Server side**

```
>received<SingleWord  //server receives this- good.  
IamServer             // Now server sends some message
```

**Client side**   /// I had to press enter several times to get the entire message

```
echo> Ia> 
echo> mS> 
echo> er> 
echo> ve> 
echo> r
```

Please help me resolve this:

The code is given below.

**Server.c**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/un.h> 
#define SOCK_PATH "echo_socket"

int main(void) {
    int s, s2, t, len;
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
    char str[100];
    char str2[100];
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    unlink(local.sun_path);
    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr * ) & local, len) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (listen(s, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }
    for (;;) {
        int done, n;
        printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr * ) & remote, & t)) == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connected.\n");
        done = 0;
        do {
            while (1) {
                n = recv(s2, str, 100, 0);
                printf(">received<%s", str);
                if (n <= 0) {
                    if (n < 0) perror("recv");
                    printf("error");
                    done = 1;
                }
                //m = fgets(str2,100,stdin);
                if (!done)
                    while (fgets(str2, 100, stdin) > 0) {
                        if (send(s2, str2, strlen(str2), 0) < 0) {
                            perror("send");
                            //if (send(s2, str2, m, 0) < 0) {
                            //perror("send");
                            done = 1;
                        }
                    }
            }
        } while (!done);
        close(s2);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

**Client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <errno.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <sys/un.h> 
#define SOCK_PATH "echo_socket"

int main(void) {
    int s, t, len;
    struct sockaddr_un remote;
    char str[100];
    char str2[100];
    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Trying to connect...\n");
    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr * ) & remote, len) == -1) {
        perror("connect");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connected.\n");
    while (1) {
        while (printf("> "), fgets(str, 100, stdin), !feof(stdin)) {
            if (send(s, str, strlen(str), 0) < 0) {
                perror("send");
                exit(1);
            }
            if ((t = recv(s, str2, strlen(str2), 0)) > 0) {
                str2[t] = '\0';
                printf("echo> %s", str2);
            } else {
                if (t < 0) perror("recv");
                else printf("Server closed connection\n");
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
    close(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indentation would ne great, not everyone is sufficiently smart and fluent in C socket programming to write or read code without indentation.

Comment: Without looking deeply, I'm assuming that the problem is related to blocking IO, since you don't make any effort to switch to nonblocking.

Comment: this line: if ((t = recv(s, str2, strlen(str2), 0)) > 0) { is trying to get the length of a string in the array str2 however, there has been nothing put into that array until AFTER the recv() has completed execution.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number a little problems in your code :

- server.c :

  - after the `n = recv(s2, str, 100, 0);`, you do not null terminate str before using it - you should have :

    ```
    n = recv(s2, str, 100, 0);
    str[(n > 0) ? n : 0] = '\0';
    ```
  - the `while(1)` should be a `while (! done)`, if you get an error, you get an infinite loop displaying the error - you should have :

    ```
    do {
        while (! done) {
    ```
- client.c :

  - you use a `strlen` in `recv` at `t = recv(s, str2, strlen(str2), 0)` - should be :

    ```
    if ((t = recv(s, str2, sizeof(str2), 0)) > 0) {
    ```
  - the `while (1) { while (printf("> "), fgets(str, 100, stdin), !feof(stdin))` does not do what you expect, if eof on stdin, the outer loop continues - you could write (provided `int done = 0` is declared above) :

    ```
    while (! done) {
        done = 1;
        while (printf("> "), fgets(str, 100, stdin) != NULL) {
            done = 0;
    ```

And I do not guarantee there are no other little problems of same type, and you should do IO multiplexing with `select` because for now, client and server must talk each in turn.

Comment: +1. You should also note that stream sockets don't guarantee that messages are sent as full units.

Comment: I agree with using the select() function before the recv(), all in a loop until a select() timeout occurs.  You need to add some method of determining if the full message has been received before trying to print it.  The select() timeout would be a simple method of determining if the full message is received.  this also means each time the recv() is executed successfully, the read characters should be concatinated to what is already read.  Also, each of the buffers should be initialized to all '\0' before each usage.

Comment: @user3629249 @kmkaplan : I do agree with both of you : the programs are far from being professional grade ;-) . I just showed what whas the cause of main problems. Just one precision, the code now adds a `\0` after last character received, so I'm not sure the buffers really have to be null initialized - even if it is good practice.

Answer (score -2):

You may need to start a new thread in client to receive message from server or use I/O multiplexing。

Comment: I am using two different terminals, so it is associated with two different threads (Am I wrong?), so why do I  need to create a new thread?